# Get nested xml document in DOm java

Tags: java, xml, dom

**What am i trying to do?** - I am trying to extract the InputData document in below xml as XML(not as textContent of elements).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test>
     <Identifier>1</Identifier>
     <Mode>SYNCHRONOUS</Mode>
     <Callback>null</Callback>
     <InputData>
               <iid>
                   <test3>p</test3>
                   <test4>p1</test4>
              </iid>
     </InputData>
</Test>
```

**When i do node.item(i).textContent(), I want output as :**

```
          <iid>
               <test3>p</test3>
               <test4>p1</test4>
          </iid>
```

**What is the problem Code? -**

```
 private void doProcessing(Document xmldoc) {

            Element rootEliment = xmldoc.getDocumentElement();
            // System.out.println("NodeName : "+rootEliment.getNodeName());
            NodeList children = rootEliment.getChildNodes();
            NamedNodeMap nnl = rootEliment.getAttributes();

            Node inputdata = nnl.getNamedItem("InputData");
            // inputdata.getOwnerDocument().g
            // System.out.println("inputDataValuefirst: "+inputdata.getTextContent());
            // NodeList testList = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("InputData");
            for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
                // Element el = (Element)children.item(i);
                //System.out.println("NodeName: " + children.item(i).getNodeName()
                    //  + " TextValue: " + children.item(i).getTextContent());
                if (children.item(i).getNodeName() == "InputData") {
                    NodeList childs = children.item(i).getChildNodes();
                    for (int j = 0; j < childs.getLength(); j++) {
                        System.out.println("NodeVal;ue: "
                                + childs.item(j).getNodeName() + " Text: "
                                + childs.item(j).getTextContent());
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

**gives me:** 
NodeVal;ue: iid Text: pp1

I have also tried various other combinations. All of them give the textContent of child nodes but not the node itself. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialize your `<iid>` node into a string using an `LSSerializer`.

```
try {
    NodeList childNodes = xmldoc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = childNodes.item(i);
        if ("InputData".equals(node.getNodeName())) {
            Node iid = node.getFirstChild();
            while (!"iid".equals(iid.getNodeName())) {
                iid = iid.getNextSibling();
            }
            String iidTree = ((DOMImplementationLS) xmldoc
                    .getImplementation()).createLSSerializer()
                    .writeToString(iid);
            System.out.println(iidTree.replaceFirst("<.*?>\n", "")
                    .replaceAll("[ ]", ""));
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

***Output :***

```
<iid>
<test3>p</test3>
<test4>p1</test4>
</iid>
```

The `LSSerializer` writes out data as an XML file. The *regex* substitution just removes the XML header and normalizes the whitespaces.